Sending messages to session based service bus queue not reliable
Has anyone ever had reliability issues when sending messages to a session enabled queue in service bus using an azure function?
We have a http trigger function which uses a service bus output binding to add messages to a queue
For some reason the messages are not always delivered and received?
We need an approach that allows us to queue a lot of messages quickly
Paul

Have you proved i) The function is being invoked? ii) The ServiceBus dependency is being called every time the Function is invoked? If you don't have answers to these questions then Application Insights can help you answer them.

I am using the below code to send message to a Service Bus session enabled queue.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace _78259611
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage> outputSbQueue,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var message = new ServiceBusMessage(requestBody);
            message.SessionId = "{session_id}";

            // Add message to the session-enabled queue
            await outputSbQueue.AddAsync(message);

            return new OkObjectResult("Message sent successfully.");
        }
    }
}

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_78259611</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I am able to receive all the messages in Service Bus queue.





Not sure how this is supposed to answer the question, given that the question does not provide sufficient context.   This looks more like a generic information dump than an answer.

I understood that the OP is facing issues while sending messages to the session based service bus queue from a http triggered function, so I provided a solution which worked for me for the subjected case.
